# Do I need to reinstall rvm, git, rails etc when I create new user account on mac?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos

I've set up a new user account on my mac so I can let a pair programmer ssh into my computer, does this mean I have to reinstall rvm and rails and configure my bash files and terminal window and all that messing about or is there a magic way of transferring everything over to the new user account as is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how things have been installed. If git and other utilities have been installed under /opt or /usr/local, the new user could just add the relevant 'bin' directories to their PATH and pick those up "for free".

With rvm, I think part of the design goal is to completely sandbox each user and application into their own environment if necessary. So sharing your rvm installation is probably not a good idea.